# Why autoescape cannot substitute safe in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am a beginner in Django and working on the template and get confused on autoescape and |safe. I thought autoescape could substitute |safe, but it is not. I don't know why.

Following is my code. Could anyone help me out? Thanks a lot.

`|safe` works well:

```
{% block title %}
    {{ name|safe }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{ description|safe }}
{% endblock %}
```

`autoescape` does not work:

```
{% autoescape on %}

{% block title %}
    {{ name }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{ description }}
{% endblock %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Everything outside the `{% block %}` will not be rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything outside the [**`{% block … %} … {% endblock %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#block) will not be rendered, you thus will need to write this as:

```
{% block title %}
  {% autoescape on %}
    {{ name }}
  {% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  {% autoescape on %}
    {{ description }}
  {% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. But why things outside of {% block %} cannot be rendered?

Comment: @johnwow: because that is how template inheritance is implemented. If you write `{% extends %}`, it will first render the "parent" template, and then replace the blockps with the blocks defined in the "child template". It ignores all the rest.

Comment: Got it. I will read this part in the documentation again. Thanks!